# Mongoose Array Push Fails

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Mongoose schema with, among other things, an array of objects like so:

```
multipleThings: [{
    field1: String,
    field2: String,
    field3: String,
    thingId  : { type: ObjectId, default: ObjectId }
}]
```

In my code I do a `.findOne`, which returns my object. `myObject.multipleThings` is an `Array[0]` at this point. I simply want to push something to this array, so I do

```
myObject.multipleThings.push(anObjectICreated)
```

And I get

> undefined is not a function
>
> at DocumentArray.SchemaType.applySetters (.../node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:570:26)
>
> at Array.MongooseArray.mixin.push (.../node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/array.js:292:27)
>
> at {The location of .push above in my code}

I don't understand what is stopping me from being able to push to the array?

Comment: Can you post the Schema definition?

Answer (score 0):

I am still new to this as well put may I suggest you try `myObject.multipleThings[0].push(anObjectICreated)`